# I don't want to stop test when access violation in test with boost library

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test

When occur to access violation in unit test with boost test library.

and then, test was aborted, and finished.

But, I don't want to stop the unit test. Just I want to get exception or notification.

How do I?

Thank you, and please understad my fool english (8(|)

EDIT!

Access violation error is not in test program. It is in the target program(be tested).

for example.

target program

```
int target_function()
{
  char *source;

  strcpy(source, "access violation");

  return 0;
}
```

test program

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(access_violation)
{
  target_function();
  BOOST_CHECK(false);
}
```

EDIT!!!

I use visual studio 2005 in windows system and g++ in linux system, too.

EDIT!!!
I understood your opinion. But, I am not target program programer. So, I can't fix them.
I just want to continue my test program. I make a lot of test case. So. whenever my test program meet the any error, pass that error and go on.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What operating system are you running on?

Answer (score 2):

When you have an access violation, the integrity of the process as a whole is compromised. There's no sane way to recover from this condition; and therefore no sane way to continue testing. When the process corrupts itself, the process is going down, whether the unit test framework would like it to or not.

Comment: Is it impossible catch access violation as 'try', 'catch'?

Comment: @cardbt Depending on your OS and such, there may be ways to catch it. But wouldn't it be better just to fix the source of the access violation instead of trying to bypass it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe methods used to attempt to catch access violations are implementation defined.  However, this is a bad idea any way you cut it.  If your program is crashing and burning, you might as well abort the testing process anyway and just fix the problem before continuing.